# Highlight tab and setting it as default

Tags: html

i am trying to set it monthly tab as highlighted by default.

This link shows both tab unselected.
[image]

This link shows the monthly tab is selected.
[image]

the follow code for that is

```
   <!-- Navigation Tabs starts -->
                          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
                            <li><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2"  aria-selected="true" aria-checked="true"  role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Navigation Tabs ends -->
```

As you can see the i tried to add a few condition into the second tab, however nothing happen. May i know what or what should be done. Thank you very much.

Comment: you have to active class name in tab 2 by default.. inspect what class has to be added as default in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `class='active'` to the tab2:

```
<!-- Navigation Tabs starts -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
    <li><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2"  aria-selected="true" aria-checked="true"  role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a></li>
     </ul>
<!-- Navigation Tabs ends -->
```

PS: I assume you are using the bootstrap framework. 
Check this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs&stacked=h) for more insights and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp) for more details.

Comment: thank you sir, yes this is the way and got it working. haha thanks alot